# Get sum of a column from mongodb along with the list of another column

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection "employees" with sample entries as  below-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62ccaa238a322322211"),
    "employeeId" : "1234",
    "date" : ISODate("2022-07-11T12:00:00.000+0000"),
    "hours" : 15.0,
    "createdBy" : "user1",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2023-02-19T21:54:27.213+0000"),
    "updatedBy" : "user1",
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2023-02-19T21:54:27.213+0000"),
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62ccaa238a322388821"),
    "employeeId" : "1234",
    "date" : ISODate("2022-07-10T12:00:00.000+0000"),
    "hours" : 25.0,
    "createdBy" : "user1",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2023-02-19T22:54:27.213+0000"),
    "updatedBy" : "user1",
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2023-02-19T22:54:27.213+0000"),
}
```

I am trying to get sum of hours for each employee along with the list of dates for those entries

```
{
    employeeId :"1234"
    hours : 40 // sum of the hours from both entries
    dates : [2022-07-11, 2022-07-10] // list of `date` column
}
```

I tried below one but dont know how to adapt to get employeeId and sum

```
db.getCollection("employees").aggregate( [
  { $match : {
      $and :[
            {"employeeId" : "1234"},
             {"date" : { $lte: new ISODate("2023-02-19") }}
    ]}},
  {
       $group:
         {
           "_id": {
      "$dateToString": {
        "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
        "date": "$date"
      }
    },
           totalAmount: { $sum: "$hours" }
         }
     }
] )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group by employeeId instead of date.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$employeeId",
      hours: {
        $sum: "$hours"
      },
      dates: {
        $push: {
          $dateTrunc: {
            date: "$date",
            unit: "day"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LhL9cVEEIKC)